# Unit test check old compilations, dont see changes in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, console-application

i am working in tic-tac-toe n and i got troble with test, It seems dont get update code, and always work with old compilations

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ComprobarVictoria_Medio_Juego()
    {
        testJugador = new Jugador("claudio", 0);
        testJuego = new Juego(new Tablero(4, 4));

        testJuego.participantes.Add(testJugador);

        testJugador.AsignarFicha(new Ficha("Negras", testJugador));


        Assert.IsTrue(testJuego.ComprobarGanadorMedio(0,0,0)); 

    }
```

this is the error that I have

[image: Screenshot of exception message]

and now check the code

```
public bool ComprobarGanadorMedio(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

I made the change method to return true, for check if the error was my code or the test, and continuous give me error in no exits line
[In line 30 and its empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDhPo.png)

it seems got the old code, and dont see changes.

I try compile, debug... dont work,
any ideas?

Comment: First close your test runner windows. Then Click on Clean Solution. Then Click on Rebuild Solution. Then try again. If this doesn't work, manually delete the files in your build output directory and run the tests again.

Comment: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` clearly states that error happens in the `Juego` class where you trying to access array with index outside of array size. Looks like `new Tablero(4, 4)` can be a reason

Comment: @Fabio i explain in question. I testing this method i get the error, i try to fix but always test say false. And i change ALL code of method and put return true. And test still says false.

Comment: @swdon i try rebuild solution but dont woek, tomorow will try delenting local files. Sorry for dont answer, i remake code in other project, but i still intersted in solve this troble

Comment: Turn Visual Studio on and off again ;)